# Chemstyle creates export error

Tags: mhchem, chemstyle, chemnum

So I finally got everything working after having to add several packages I never thought I'd have to. Live preview shows a perfect manuscript, but for some reason, when I go to export, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemstyle/chemstyle.sty:441: LaTeX Error: Command \c@scheme already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

￼l.441 ...\@nameuse{cst@float@make@\cst@float@pkg}}
```

When I click on the link (I'm using LaTeXian) it brings me to the `chemstyle.sty` file, highlighting this line of code:

```
\cst@float@execute{\@nameuse{cst@float@make@\cst@float@pkg}}
```

I'm not sure what to do, as I don't want to ruin the `.sty` file.

Here's also a typical scheme formatting:

```
\begin{scheme}[htb]
    \schemeref[TMP6]{cmpd:cyclenam}
    \schemeref[TMP7]{cmpd:cyclylide}
    \schemeref[TMP8]{cmpd:cyclindole}
    \schemeref[TMP9]{cmpd:cyclinter}

    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/photolysis.eps}
    \end{center}

\caption{Proposed mechanism of photochemical cyclization}
\label{sch:photolysis}
\end{scheme}
```

Here is my document header:

```
\documentclass[super,compress]{proposalnsf} %super=superscript citations, compress=compressed citations
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum,chemstyle} %chemnum,
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}


\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{psyr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{psyr}{m}{n}{<-> psyr}{}
\def\times{{\fontfamily{psyr}\selectfont\char180}}


%Chemical Equation Formatting

\newcounter{reaction}
\renewcommand\thereaction{\arabic{reaction}}

\renewcommand{\thereaction}{\arabic{reaction}}
\newcommand{\thealignedreaction}{\arabic{equation}}

%changing the equation tag appereance when amsmath has been loaded
\makeatletter
  \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{[#1]\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{reactionalign}{%
    \mathchardef\c@mainequation\c@equation
    \protected@edef\themainequation{\theequation}%
    \let\theequation\thealignedreaction
    \global\c@equation\c@reaction
    }%
    {
    \global\c@equation\c@mainequation
    \global\@ignoretrue
    }
\makeatother


\newcommand{\thesubreaction}{\themainreaction\alph{equation}}

\makeatletter   
\newenvironment{subreactions}{%
    \refstepcounter{reaction}%
    \mathchardef\c@mainequation\c@equation
    \protected@edef\themainequation{\theequation}%
    \mathchardef\c@mainreaction\c@reaction
    \protected@edef\themainreaction{\thereaction}%
    \let\theequation\thesubreaction
    \global\c@equation\z@
    }{%
    \global\c@reaction\c@mainreaction
    \global\c@equation\c@mainequation
    \global\@ignoretrue
    }
\makeatother

%figure counting rules
%\counterwithin{figure}{section}

% this handles hanging indents for publications
\def\rrr#1\\{\par
\medskip\hbox{\vbox{\parindent=2em\hsize=6.12in
\hangindent=4em\hangafter=1#1}}}

\def\baselinestretch{1}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A few remarks: I believe you should use `\centering` inside the `{scheme}` environment instead of adding an additional `{center}` environment. `chemstyle` loads `chemscheme` (=no need to load it explicitly). Your use of `\schemeref` suggests you use `chemcompounds` (loaded by `chemstyle`) for the compound numbering. Why do you load `chemnum`, too?

Comment: You need to load `chemscheme` _after_ `chemstyle` if you want to load it explicitly (then the error should disappear).

Comment: Ah okay, there is my error. I just got rid of the explicit call for `chemscheme` and everything is resolved.

Comment: @Nucleophilicrxn In that case, probably 'too localized' a question